# How to create your own dataset with Python for Deep Learning (Keras / Tensorflow) in Road Line detection

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I am given the task to find road lines on an image for a class project.

I want to start writing Convolutional Neural Network to do the task, but I am not sure how to create a dataset.

Let's say I have to find lines on this image (originally I have been given arround 1000 images of traffic where road lines could be detected):

[image: roadlines]

To be able to do that I have to create a dataset. What to do? Should I take some random images and cut regions where I can see the road lines? What size should the training images be? How would I label the line to stand out from the background?

Also, I presume cutting lines from an image is an okay way when the line is segmented, but I cannot do that for a full line, can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on the assignment details. What does "find road lines on an image" mean?

Depending on the answer to the above question, you could divide the image in a 4x4 or 5x5 grid and try to find the cells on that grid that contain road lines.

To accomplish that you could manually label some of the cells (you might want to create a small GUI to facilitate this part) and train your CNN with the labeled data.

Comment: Like the shown image, there are white segmented lines that mark up the road, so I am not sure how to create a dataset to teach the network what segmented line is.

Comment: If I understood you properly, I should take the image like: 1200 x 800 pixels, divide it into kernels of some size and label whether the kernel contains the interesting feature or not?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Do you possibly know of an online tutorial on how to implement the algorithm using the technique you've told me?

Comment: Any image recognition tutorial would be enough for that. I just searched on google and https://medium.com/nybles/create-your-first-image-recognition-classifier-using-cnn-keras-and-tensorflow-backend-6eaab98d14dd seems like a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks! Not what I needed but, I think we didn't understand each other, my mistake. I realised just know what you were aiming for.